# Getting offset by 1 day when converting NTP time to date

Tags: c++, math, time, ntp

I'm trying to implement my own NTP client.

I can send and recieve NTP messages and what I need to do now is to convert it to "real" time. I have created a function to do this, but for some reason I get all the fields correct, except for the day field which is 1 day behind.

I've also done some quick calculations with pen, paper and a calculator and I get the same results so there must be something I'm missing.

Here is my code:

```
void setTime(uint32_t seconds, uint32_t fraction)
{
    int yearsPassed = seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365);

    year = 1900 + yearsPassed;

    int leapYears = yearsPassed / 4;

    int secondsLeft = seconds - yearsPassed * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;

    secondsLeft -= leapYears * 60 * 60 * 24;

    int daysPassed = secondsLeft / (60 * 60 * 24);

    secondsLeft -= daysPassed * 60 * 60 * 24;

    int hoursPassed = secondsLeft / (60*60);

    secondsLeft -= hoursPassed * 60 * 60;

    int minutesPassed = secondsLeft / 60;

    secondsLeft -= minutesPassed * 60;

    hour = hoursPassed + SUMMERTIME_OFFSET;
    minute = minutesPassed;
    second = secondsLeft;

    us = (fraction * (pow((float)10,(float)6)) / (pow((float)2,(float)32)));

    month = getMonth(daysPassed);
    day = getDay(month, daysPassed);
}
```

With this code I can for example get the time 2015/4/28 14:3:15.351731 but the date should be 29 instead of 28. My initial thought was that I calculated wrong for leap years and was missing 1 day from that, but that appears to be correct.

**EDIT**

Code for getMonth() and getDay(). They are not fully implemented yet since I wanted to write as little code as possible just to test that it works.

```
int getMonth(int daysPassed)
{
    if (daysPassed < 32)
        return 1;
    else if (daysPassed < 60)
        return 2;
    else if (daysPassed < 91)
        return 3;
    else if (daysPassed < 121)
        return 4;
    else if (daysPassed < 152)
        return 5;
    else 
        return 6;
}

int getDay(int month, int daysPassed)
{
    switch (month)
    {
    case 1:
        return daysPassed;
        break;
    case 2:
        return daysPassed - 31;
        break;
    case 3:
        return daysPassed - 59;
        break;
    case 4:
        return daysPassed - 90;
        break;
    case 5:
        return daysPassed - 120;
        break;
    default:
        return 6;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please print the values of all the variables there and add it to the question? That would save people a lot of time calculating or reimplementing your code. Chances are, you will spot the problem yourself when doing it.

Comment: What does your `getDay(...)` and `getMonth(...)` look like (and also, why don't they need to know whether they're in a leap year?

Comment: ...and how do they work for Jan 1 1900?

Comment: @Roland Shaw I ignored the leap year aspect for the current date while i tried to get it to work, since it's not a leap year this year

Comment: @AlexNevidomsky How they work for Jan 1 1900? You mean if I pass 0 to the setTime() function? It shows 1900/01/00. Does this mean you always have to add one extra day?

Comment: Calendrical algorithms that could be handy for this project: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a fencepost error on your `daysPast`, as it is the *completed* days, and not the number of *partial* days.

Consider an input of 1 second (heck, better still, make it a unit test), which should resolve to 1/1/1900 00:00:01 - it would give your `daysPast` as 0 which whilst is the number of days past, it doesn't account for the current day.

Of course, you'll also need to take into account whether the current year is a leap year when calculating the day in year; and for completeness, and for compatibility in the year 2100, your leap years past algorithm is a smidge naive.

Comment: Ok, so I alwasys need to add 1 extra day? And I'm completely aware that my functions for getting the current day/month doesn't account for leap years, I just wanted to test it with as little code as possible before I continued. And what is special about year 2100?

Comment: The year 2100 is not a leap year (in the same way 1900 wasn't), even though it is divisible by 4, as it was divisible by 100, and not by 400. And yes, you need to fix your fencepost error by possible adjusting the result of `getDay`, and adjusting your offsets in `getMonth`